# Отправка письма с несколькими вложениями

Tags: email, php

Пусть имеется массив имен файлов $file такого вида:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => asd.txt
        [1] => asdd.txt
        [2] => asddd.txt
    )
```

Данный массив передается в функцию send_mail, которая обрабатывает его и отправляет письмо с несколькими вложениями. Это в теории, а на практике приходит только последнее вложение. Вот функция:

```
    function send_mail($email, $subject, $msg, $from, $file)
    {
        $boundary = "--" . md5(uniqid(time()));
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"\n";
        $headers .= "From: $from\n";
        $multipart = "--$boundary\n";
        $multipart .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
        $multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quot-Printed\n\n";
        $multipart .= "$msg\n\n";
        foreach ($file as $key => $value) {
           $fp = fopen($value, "r");
           $file = fread($fp, filesize($value));
           $message_part = "--$boundary\n";
           $message_part .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream\n";
           $message_part .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
           $message_part .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$value\"\n\n";
           $message_part .= chunk_split(base64_encode($file)) . "\n";
        }
        $multipart .= $message_part . "--$boundary--\n";

        mail($email, $subject, $multipart, $headers);
    }
```

Вопрос, соответственно, такой - где зарыта собака?

Comment: в [rfc говорят CRLF](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2046#section-5.1.1), т.е. заканчивайте строки заголовков "\r\n";

Comment: Спасибо. Кстати, возможно не все, т.к. при исправлении всех заголовков файлы начинают приходить по 0кб, в общем, там где стоит просто \n можно заменить на \r\n, в других случаях оставить \n\n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все, исправил сам :)
Дело в том, что за каждую итерацию foreach заново скреплял заголовки. Нужно просто вынести за foreach `$message_part = "";`а внутри самого цикла добавить точку в `$message_part .= "--$boundary\n";` , чтобы он именно среплял, а не обнулял старое значение.

Comment: я бы вынес строку

    $message_part = "--$boundary\n";

перед циклов в виде 

    $multipart .= "--$boundary\n";

а строку

    $multipart .= $message_part . "--$boundary--\n";

внес бы внутрь цикла.

Так, как вы решили этот вопрос, то уже разумнее будет совсем не использовать `$message_part`, а продолжать все сливать в `$multipart`

Comment: Да, можно и так. В моем случае можно вообще без $message_part = ""; обойтись. Проблему решала всего одна точка :)